# How to return an empty SubSequence in a Collection extension

Tags: swift, collections

I am creating an extension to `Collection` which returns a `SubSequence`. However, if the function's condition isn't valid I want to return an empty `SubSequence` instead of nil.

How can I return an empty `SubSequence` in an extension to `Collection`?

```
// basic example:
extension Collection {

   func myFunction(condition: Bool) -> SubSequence {
      guard condition else {
          return *EmptySubSequence*
      }
      ...
   }

}
```

This would be very easy if I just did an extension on a concrete type, but before I limit my extension to a specific type, I would like to know if it can apply to `Collection` itself.

The best I've found is `prefix(0)` will return a `SubSequence` of length 0.

Comment: What's wrong with `prefix(0)`?

Comment: @Sweeper I guess nothing significant, but an initializer seems more correct than abusing a function with desired effects. Internally, prefix would create a buffer and then perform a for loop. An empty `init` will be optimized, like `EmptyCollection`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to initialize an empty collection you should extend `RangeReplaceableCollection` instead of `Collection`. [`RangeReplaceableCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rangereplaceablecollection) requires the types which conform to it to implement an empty initializer.

---

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection {
    func myFunction(condition: Bool) -> SubSequence {
        guard condition else {
            return .init()
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! I can't see why Collection wouldn't define `init()` and only `RangeReplaceableCollection` would define `init()`.

Comment: There is many methods that will only be available when extending RangeReplaceableCollection. Collection protocol is very basic it only requires the types that conforms to it to implement startIndex, endIndex, read-only access subscript and index(after:) method.

Comment: @MichaelOzeryansky Consider a class  a collection type like the built in `CollectionOfOne`, or the often hand-rolled "NonEmptyArray". They would be impossible to implement if `Collection` mandated that all collections can be initialized as empty.

Comment: @Alexander Makes a lot of sense. I've never heard of a `NonEmptyArray`, seems I could have used that in many places.

Comment: @MichaelOzeryansky Yeah, it can be pretty handy, since it can provide a `first` and `last property that are non-optional. Though it's currently impossible to implement a protocol requirement of type `T?` with a property of type `T`, so you need to introduce new names for the non-optional variants

Answer (score 1):

While I believe Leo's answer is very helpful, I wouldn't use it in this case. There is no need to add an additional requirement such as RangeReplaceableCollection, which also adds a `replaceSubrange` requirement. Adding these requirements limits the extension more than needed. For example, Range is not a RangeReplaceableCollection. (If you really only plan to ever call this on Array, then I recommend making that explicit and forget about Collection.)

Creating a "fresh" subsequence means that it becomes unrelated to the original collection, and that breaks the meaning of the indices. Calling `init` is going create something with a "zero-like" start index that may not be compatible with the collection you're working on. You can't safely compare indices from different collections, even of the same type.

Sweeper's recommendation of `prefix(0)` is better, but I think anchoring to the beginning isn't helpful for common algorithms that would need this.

Instead, I recommend a subsequence at the end of the collection: `self[endIndex...]`.

Consider an algorithm for `myFunction` that processes some portion of the collection, possibly skipping over some part, and returning the first "important" part (i.e. a first stage of a tokenizer that skips over whitespace). The `endIndex` would naturally tell you the last place it looked, and allow you to start the next search at that point. Returning an empty subsequence *from this collection* means that the indices are always compatible. You can always safely set `startSearchingFrom = result.endIndex`, even in the case that it's empty.

In most cases, getting the indices right won't matter. But in most cases, you probably just wanted to use this on Array anyway and it didn't need to be generic. If you are going to make it generic, IMO you should make sure to keep all the semantics of the types you're working on, and that means getting the indices right.

Comment: Well Rob... `prefix(0)` was my own recommendation. I was actually using this on `Data` but I know it can be useful for `Array` and `String`. My application is a BLE app so I'm using `Array` and `Data` quite often, so any extension that can apply to a lower protocol is always best for me. More opinions is always nice, but I believe Leo's answer to be correct, especially in the context of Swift itself.